# Ember hasMany on a single route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am working on Employee and employee can have multiple addresses, When added/editing an employee, addresses are on the same route/page.

On the page I have Add Address button, when that is clicked it should add address fields' set

here is some code

```
addAddress: function () {

  const addressNew = this.store.createRecord('employee/address', {});
  ////addressNew.set('id', 999);

  const employee = this.controller.get('model');
  employee.get('address').pushObject(addressNew);
},
```

When I press add address button, it gives me error

```
Uncaught Error: You must provide a string key when calling `yieldItem`; you provided null
```

When I uncomment the ID line, it adds one address, but when I click 2nd time it give me duplicate ID message.

What should be the proper way to handle hasMany relation on the single page

Models

```
// employee 
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  fname: DS.attr('string'),
  lname: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  department: DS.attr('string'),
  hire_date: DS.attr('date'),
  status: DS.attr('boolean'),
  gmail: DS.attr('string'),
  timezone: DS.attr('string'),
  address: DS.hasMany('employee/address')
});


// employee/address
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  address_1: DS.attr('string'),
  address_2: DS.attr('string'),
  phone: DS.attr('string'),
  cell: DS.attr('string'),
  city: DS.attr('string'),
  state: DS.attr('string'),
  country: DS.attr('string'),
  default_address: DS.attr('boolean'),
  employee_id: DS.belongsTo('employee')
});
```

I am using

```
DEBUG: Ember             : 1.13.7
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 1.13.8
DEBUG: jQuery            : 2.1.4
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 0.8.0
```

**Edit**

I think it is something with my template that it is not allowing me to add and give me error I am using

```
{{#each model.address key="id" as |address|}}
```

to loop, so it dont have ID and it give yield error. I changed `key="@guid"` and it worked. I need a unique index as well, and `@guid` or `@index` are not working ...

Comment: You don't need to pass 2nd parameter to `createRecord`. Just `this.store.createRecord('modelName')`

Comment: As you suggested it gave me `Uncaught Error: You must provide a string key when calling 'yieldItem'; you provided null` error

Comment: Maybe something wrong with model definition. Also, there is no reason to use const in your code.

Comment: Changed const to var, same issue. I have added model's definition in the question

Comment: Please check updated question. I think it is something with the template each loop,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gennady Dogaev suggested, I changed it. My issue was with the template

I was using

```
{{#each model.address key="id" as |address|}}
```

I have changed that to

```
{{#each model.address as |address index|}}
```

now it is working fine as expected